# Can Heckling Fiends cause a creature to attack on an opponent’s turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can [Heckling Fiends](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHeckling%20Fiends%5d)' activated ability cause an opponent to attack on another player's turn?

> {2}{R}: Target creature attacks this turn if able.

Comment: The way to look at it is this, if the controller wanted to attack with that creature, could they? If it's tapped, the answer is no, if it's summoning sick, no, if it's not their turn, the answer is no. If there's anything that prevents the creature from attacking, they are not able, the ability says 'if able'.

Answer (score 7):

No, Heckling Fiend cannot cause a creature to attack unless that creature would be otherwise able to attack in the first place. The “if able” in the text makes this clear.

You cannot declare attackers if it is not your turn, so you would not be able to attack with he targeted creature if it is not your turn. Similarly, a tapped creature would not be able to attack; or a creature that is destroyed before he combat phase.

Comment: With the single exemption of [Party Crasher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439481). Though silver borders rarely count.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this doesn't prevent someone from using Heckling Fiends on a creature belonging to the non active player, the ability will resolve and the creature will get the condition. However when declare attacker checks the condition, it will determine that the creature is not able to attack and thus the condition will do nothing.

Comment: @Andrew (to continue your thought) this is relevant as certain effects care if a creature has been targeted (ie.[mtg:Crystalline Nautilus], [mtg:Daru Spiritualist] etc.). So just because it won't normally do anything doesn't mean that using the ability when the creature can't attack is always useless.

Comment: @Malco Exactly, usually you would do the nautilus/illusion targets with an ability like this, there are easier ways to do the beneficial targets for your own creatures [Shuko](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=74415) for instance. Also mtg doesn't work for links in comments.